# Factor Analysis Cumulative Explained Variance Exceeding 100% when k-factors < p-variables

Tags: factor-analysis, statsmodels

I'm new to Factor Analysis and having a rather frustrating result. I'm using the Factor Analysis implementation from statsmodels in Python with 119 variables and would like to reduce down to k-factors.

If I initiate the number of factors to be the same as the number of variables (like so)

```
EFA = Factor(endog_df, n_factor=119).fit(maxiter=100)
```

The cumulative proportion of the explained variance is ~0.35 generated by the code below and shown in subsequent plot

```
EFA.plot_scree(ncomp=10).show()
```

[image]

If instead, however, I change the number of factors extracted by the model to 10, the cumulative variance explained skyrockets (see code and plot below)

```
EFA = Factor(endog_df, n_factor=10).fit(maxiter=100)
EFA.plot_scree(ncomp=10).show()
```

[image]

I also noticed that when I pass only 10 features for extraction, 119 eigenvalues are still returned in the results (even though loadings for only 10 factors are generated). I am new to Factor analysis and did not find anyone else posting about this phenomenon online. So I am wondering, is this something that is normal/expected, indicative of an error in my approach/data-processing, or potentially an issue with the statsmodels package. Any help would be greatly appreciated!